# ODT file opening as left aligned page

Tags: html, doc, odt, libreoffice-writer

I'm writing into a file with some HTML table content.

Now when I save it in .doc extension, then while opening it with Libre writer shows the content in center of the page.
But same when I save it with .odt extension the page shows at the left side of the window. Why this is happening and how can I bring it to center?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`Tools > Options... > Load/Save > General`** and make sure **Load user-specific settings with the document** is checked.

As far as I've been able to tell, each document will open with the same page view setting as the last saved document of that type unless that option is selected.

If you have a particular document that opens in with a page view setting you don't want, you should be able to change it by clicking the 'Single-page view' or 'Multiple-page view' icon for the desired page view and resaving the file.